# Python: sys.stdin in select doesn't work

Tags: python, select

I'm searching a way to read from console OR get data from socket. I want to use this

```
test = select.select([sys.stdin, socket],[],[],waitTime)
```

but I get always this error:

```
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

I know this is a typical Windows error, but I'm working on Ubuntu. Anyone knows how to solve this error?

Comment: If you print socket.fileno() before that line, do you get a valid int? Also, you probably shouldn't name your socket "socket".

Comment: It's not a socket problem, I tested it without sys.stdin and it worked well. The problem is the console input sys.stdin.
Anyway "socket" is a placeholder, in my code has another name.

Comment: Did you modify `sys.stdin`? `select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 1)` works on the 2 machines I tested on (Mac OS, Ubuntu).

Comment: I tested it on my Mac OS and Ubuntu and doesn't work in either. I tested sys.stdin.fileno() and it gives me AttributeError. Modify how? I just installed Ubuntu...

Comment: Alright then. Does sys.stdin.fileno() give you 0?

Comment: It gives me 'AttributeError:fileno'

Comment: Modified somewhere in your python code? Can you `print sys.stdin`?

Comment: That would be a problem. Do you do anything with "sys" or "sys.stdin" earlier in your script?  Or are you invoking your script in a weird way that closes stdin first?

Comment: I solved the problem, it was IDLE's fault. Starting the program from console works well :D